# Is service available to others Angular?

Tags: angular

I have local module, that contains all information about services and components.

This module is included in main module `app.module`. Does that mean, that services described in local module are available in root module? Or it is isolated structure?

For example, I have `header.component` that includes some others components, that use services. To join all logic together I have created module `header.module`. Where described all services.

If I have imported already service in `app.module`, do I need import this service in local module or not?

Comment: If you have imported your services in root module then there is not need to import in feature modules they are accessible to your entire application. But if imported in feature module then only accessible to the parts or components of the feature module

Comment: Please provide source code examples of what you're trying to ask.

Comment: I would suggest not to use services in providers of modules instead use `@Injectable({providedIn: 'your moodule name or root'})` so that you can leverage tree shaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide your Service to the module, it will be available for **all the Components of this module** (one shared instance).

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
  BackendService,
  Logger
 ],
 ...
})
```

or (since Angular 6)

```
@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root',
})
```

---

If you provide your Service to the Component, it will be available **only for this Component**.

```
@Component({
  selector:    'app-hero-list',
  templateUrl: './hero-list.component.html',
  providers:  [ HeroService ]
})
```

[Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services#providing-services)